# Gedit Ruby 1.9.x syntax highlighting

Tags: gedit, ruby

I have a problem with **Gedit** and it's way of highlighting new Ruby syntax. In **Ruby 1.9.x**, we can write Hash this way:

```
{ class: 'class_name', id: 'uniq_id' }
```

instead of

```
{ :class => 'class_name', :id => 'uniq_id' }
```

In new syntax, Gedit highlights `class:` as keyword instead of symbol.

Is there any solution to make Gedit highlight Ruby syntax the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Your boggle actually lies with GtkSourceView and the file `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/ruby.lang`. At least I think it's that version. You might want `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/ruby.lang` if changing 3.0 does nothing.

Anyway, you'll need to hack around in there to fix the syntax. And I suggest you push the change up to the gtksourceview maintainers so other people can benefit.

---

Or look at the following: https://github.com/janlelis/rubybuntu-language-specs

They seem to have updated the specs and they provide instructions for installing it in a 2.0 environment (should be simple enough to adapt).